# Global variable, unable to close connection

Tags: php, mysqli, global-variables, database-connection

```
global $link;

function linkDb() {

    $hostname = 'xxxxx';
    $username = 'xxxxxx';
    $password = 'xxxxxx';
    $database = 'xxxxxx';

    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

    if (!$link) {
        echo ('Error: Could not make a database link using provided credentials');
        die();
            } 

            if (!mysqli_select_db($link, $database)) {
        echo ('Error: Could not connect to database');
        die();
    }   

    return $link;           
}

function unlinkDb() {
    mysqli_close($link);    
}
```

Above code file is included at the top of second file and i am trying to close the database connection,

```
unlinkDb();
```

but its saying

```
"ERROR: Undefined variable: link "
```

i am confuse.

Comment: You need to define $link as global __inside__ your functions to give scope to it in those functions.... there's no point in defining it global outside, because it already is global there

Comment: tried this either, but its not working. :(

Comment: ...that is, in _every_ function that uses the global `$link` you must identify it as `global $link;` Don't do that at the higher scope, do it in the functions. Better still, use `$GLOBALS['link']` and better _still_, pass `$link` as a parameter to the functions that need it.

Comment: Your solution resembles 2 of the answers already given below. @farhanahmed why not accept one of them to close the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `global` keyword *inside* of your function:

```
function unlinkDb() {
    global $link;
    mysqli_close($link);    
}
```

Then use it as such:

```
$link = linkDb();
unlinkDb();
```

Although a better solution is to not use the `global` keyword and pass `$link` as a parameter to `linkDb()`:

```
$link = linkDb();
unlinkDb($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function definations as here:

```
function linkDb(&$link) {...}
function unlinkDb(&$link) {...}
```

Comment: But i don't want to have a parametrized function.

Comment: Why not? It's a textbook use case for function parameters.

Comment: If you want keep changes in function you must add & operator before function parameter. Otherwise changes are useable only function scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to keep the connection inside your class (I'm assuming I'm looking at a class) you can define it as a variable and refer to it from inside the instantiated object;
This way you can close/open the connection from anywhere inside your object by calling $this->linkDb(); and/or $this->unlinkDb();

```
class DBClass {
    private $link;

    function linkDb(){
       $this->link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    }

    function unlinkDb() {
        mysqli_close($this->link);    
    }
}
```

You can also pass it via the function itself (as mentioned before), assuming you're NOT working in a class:

```
function linkDb(){
    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    // Do fancy stuff
    unlinkDb($link);
}

function unlinkDb($link){
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i made the modifications to a code and changed it to following:

```
function linkDb() 
{ 
   $link = ''; 
 .............. 
} 

function unlinkDb($link) { 
   mysqli_close($link); 
}
```

in the other file, where i am opening a connection i did this:

```
$link = linkDb();
```

and in the same file call a function to close DB this way:

```
unlinkDb($link);
```

Now its working the way, that i needed. I would to thanks all here who tried to help me out.